# How to sum distinct overlapping time ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I seek to create a UDF which accepts a date range and interrogates a table to return the sum of the unique overlap of records in that table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Shifts (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Shifts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

```
Problem Statement: Given @Start and @End parameters,
write a UDF that returns the percentage of unique temporal overlap by
records in the dbo.Shifts table
Round start and stop times to the nearest 15-minutes

E.g.,

Timeline     : <---------------------------------------------------------->

Input Params :      @Start-----------------------------------@End
Input Params :      !-------------------------------------------!

Overlapping Shifts
Shift 1      :   |----------------|
Shift 2      :        |----------------|
Shift 3      :                                             |--------------|


Unique overlap
Input Params :      !-------------------------------------------!
Shifts       :      |--------------------|                   |--|

% overlap    :    ~ 58%
```

Comment: This question has been written as if it were a. homework problem.  You should include your attempts and what you don't understand.

Comment: I retired three years ago and I haven't written any T-SQL since then. So, I am a bit rusty. I got as far as stating the problem. I haven't spent too much time mulling this one over yet. And I am not sure how to partition the date ranges declaratively using SQL. I'll figure it out though and post the answer. In the meantime, maybe someone will clue me in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has two components.  The more interesting is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The second is an overlap problem.  You want to limit the gaps-and-islands to data that spans the range and then combine them.  So, to get the relevant groupings:

```
select min(starttime) as island_start, max(endtime) as island_end
from (select s.*,
             sum(case when prev_endtime >= starttime then 0 else 1 end) over (order by starttime) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(endtime) over (order by starttime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_endtime
            from shifts s
            where endtime > @start or
                  starttime < @end
           ) s
     ) s
group by grp;
```

This the innermost subquery calculates the previous end of all the shifts.  If there is no overlaps, then this row is the start of an island.  The cumulative sum then identifies all rows on the island.  And the outer query aggregates to one row per island.

Then, you want the overlap with this and the interval you care about:

```
with i as (
      select min(starttime) as island_start, max(endtime) as island_end
      from (select s.*,
                   sum(case when prev_endtime >= starttime then 0 else 1 end) over (order by starttime) as grp
            from (select s.*,
                         max(endtime) over (order by starttime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_endtime
                  from shifts s
                  where endtime > @start or
                        starttime < @end
                 ) s
           ) s
      group by grp
     )
select sum(datediff(second, interval_start, interval_end)) as shift_seconds,
       datediff(second(second, @start, @end) as overall_seconds
from (select i.*,
             (case when island_end > @endtime then @end else island_end end) as interval_end,
              (case when island_start < @start then @start else island_start end) as interval_start
      from i
     ) i;
```

The ratio you want is the ratio of the two values.

Comment: Gordon's technique worked after adjusting the CTE to select the starttime and endtime fields